# How to know how long a process has been running?

Tags: linux, bash, process, process-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check how a long a program has been running?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7870/how-to-check-how-a-long-a-program-has-been-running)

I am interested in doing this purely using bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ps` can fit your needs:

```
ps -eo pid,command,etime
```

To get information for a specific process:

```
ps -o command,etime -p PID
```