# Understanding ps elapsed time format for long running processes

Tags: process, time, ps

I'm using a `ps` command as part of an exercise to identify processes running longer than a given threshold.

I'm using the following template to get the elapsed time for a know process command:

`ps -eo etime,command | grep <something to identify a process> | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`

I notice with short-running processes, the etime (elapsed time) value takes the format `minutes:seconds` and from this I can easily determine how long a process has been running.

For very long running processes (days long), I don't understand the format.

I have a MySQL server process that `htop` shows as running for 126 hours.

Executing `ps -eo etime,command | grep mysql | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'` gives me a value of `9-03:35:32`.

My best guess is that this means 9 something, 3 hours, 35 minutes, 32 seconds. I can't figure out what the units are for the 9.

The process in question has been running 126 hours, about 5.25 days. This suggests that the 9 in the above output does not represent days. They can't be half days either as (9 * 12) hours + 3 hours + 35 minutes + 32 seconds is less than 5 days.

How do I interpret the elapsed time value I am seeing for long-running processes? What units accompany the 9 in the above output?

Comment: Here, you're seeing the POSIX time format. Minutes:seconds is the BSD time format. Linux's `ps` displays one or the other depending on the options you pass.

Comment: To double-check, try `etimes` instead of `etime` and compare the results.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html):

> In the POSIX locale, the elapsed time since the process was started, in the form:
>
> ```
> [[dd-]hh:]mm:ss
> ```
>
> where dd shall represent the number of days, hh the number of hours, mm the number of minutes, and ss the number of seconds. The dd field shall be a decimal integer. The hh, mm, and ss fields shall be two-digit decimal integers padded on the left with zeros.

So, the 9 means days, whether you believe it or not. Could you be misinterpreting the output from htop? What does top (which has a time format of `minutes:seconds`) say? Are you certain that the field you are looking at in htop is equivalent to etime? (for example, could it means 126 *minutes* of *CPU* time?)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. htop is definitely showing 126 hours, but I think this might not be wall time but some other time (perhaps CPU time). The field in htop is not equivalent to etime, I assumed wrongly here.

Comment: @JonCram Are you sure it's hours? Original top only shows minutes (i.e. it will go to minutes above 60 rather than breaking up to hours), a number like 126:37 means 126 minutes and 37 seconds. I was thinking htop might be the same. 126 hours of CPU time in 9 days seems like a lot.