# Get process elapsed time in seconds

Tags: shell, quoting

Similar to [How to check how long a process has been running?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7870), I am trying to get the elapsed time for a process in seconds in an embedded Linux system using BusyBox and `sh` (not `bash`).  The difference is that I would like it in pure seconds, not mm:ss format.

I can parse it out of the result of `ps` but am unable to get `expr` to convert from mm:ss to seconds.  Using `set -vx` to help with debugging I can see the valid `expr` command but it fails with a syntax error.  Copying and pasting it works fine.

After running this for added diagnostics:

```
root@embedded:~# set -vx
```

I enter:

```
root@embedded:~# $(/opt/bin/busybox ps -o pid,etime,time | grep 1156 | sed "s/ *[0-9]\+ \+\([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\) .*/\/opt\/bin\/busybox expr \1 \\\* 60 + \2/")
```

And get this response:

```
$(/opt/bin/busybox ps -o pid,etime,time | grep 1156 | sed "s/ *[0-9]\+ \+\([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\) .*/\/opt\/bin\/busybox expr \1 \\\* 60 + \2/")
+ /opt/bin/busybox ps -o pid,etime,time
+ grep 1156
+ sed s/ *[0-9]\+ \+\([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\) .*/\/opt\/bin\/busybox expr \1 \\* 60 + \2/
+ /opt/bin/busybox expr 2 \* 60 + 03
expr: syntax error
root@embedded:~#
```

I have additionally tried multiple layers of `\` escapes and also `''`.

**What do I need to do to get the escaping of the `*` to pass through to the `expr` command line?**

Comment: it looks to me like you have an extra "busybox" call in there; try removing the busybox part before the expr call.

Comment: This is being developed in test code where there are two copies of BusyBox.  I am explicitly using the testing version for `ps` because the system version didn't include support for `-o`.  In the second case I was just trying it out to see if there was a difference between the two binaries for `expr` as well.

Comment: Please post just your code, I'm not sure if I understand what bits are your code and what bits are traces and prompts and so on.

Comment: @Gilles, I agree.  I'll neaten it up when I get back on that system.

Answer (score 5):

`eval` might help this case...

```
~ $ $(echo expr 1 \\* 2)
+ echo expr 1 \* 2
+ expr 1 \* 2
expr: syntax error
~ $ eval $(echo expr 1 \\* 2)
+ echo expr 1 \* 2
+ eval expr 1 \* 2
+ expr 1 * 2
2
```

But it might be better to look up `/proc/$pid/stat` on Linux.

```
pid=1155
hz=$(getconf CLK_TCK)
uptime=$(awk '{print $1}' < /proc/uptime)
starttime=$(awk '{print $22}' < /proc/$pid/stat)
echo $(( ${uptime%.*} - $starttime / $hz ))
```

If `/usr/bin/getconf` is unavailable, you need to find your system's `CLK_TCK` (or `USER_HZ`) value.  I think you can assume it as 100 in most cases.

Comment: +1 for the `/proc` solution.  But don't use the `expr` method.  That code is already too complex and fragile.

Comment: Given that the only comments I've seen about ticks/jiffies are to avoid dealing with them unless you want to carefully maintain your code, I'm going to stay away from that approach (and no, I don't presently have getconf).  Your `eval` did work but I now have it working without as well. :[  I swear I tried anywhere from 0-6 `\`s before the `*` and it didn't work, but it now does with `\\*`.  Apparently I was debugging too many different avenues at once and ended up not having tested what I thought I had.  Bugger and sorry.

Answer (score 1):

assumping process is 16752 (which you seems to be able to figure out)

```
expr $(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y /proc/16752/environ )
```

where

- `date +%s` is current date in second since the epoch
- `stat -c %Y /proc/16752/environ` is "creation date" of /proc/16752/environ, that is the moment where proc #16752 was launched

edit:

- maybe `/proc/$PID/environ` is the wrong pseudo file, `/proc/$PID/exe` should be used instead.
- if time changed on host, both result from `ps -p $PID -h -o etime` and timestamp from `/proc/$PID/exe` are likely to be wrong. (unsure how to check that).

Comment: This system set's it's time on startup from the application.  Since this occurs between the process start and the checking of the process elapsed time, it is pretty much guaranteed to be wrong.  Such timestamps are generally hazardous even when not guaranteed to be a problem.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: I am glad you found a solution, are you sure there is a difference between ps'etime and my solution ?

Comment: The user (or application in my case) can change the system time between the process start and checking of elapsed time.  You can try `elapsed() { expr $(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y /proc/${MYPID}/environ ); }; sleep 10 & export MYPID=$!; elapsed; sleep 1; elapsed; sudo date +%F\ %T -s "$(date -d "$(date +%F\ %T) 1 hour ago")"; elapsed`.  My result is 0, then 1, then -3599.  Don't forget to reset your time, optionally like `sudo rdate 0.us.pool.ntp.org` (it takes a minute or two for me).  Wall clock time is a hazardous way to keep track of durations and should be avoided when uptime is usable.

Answer (score 1):

Embarrassingly, I seem to have failed to test as completely as I had thought.  It turns out that modifying what I posted in my question to contain only two escapes (`\\*`) makes it work fine.

```
root@embedded:~# $(/opt/bin/busybox ps -o pid,etime | sed -n "s/ *1155 \+\([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\).*/expr \1 \\* 60 + \2/p")
$(/opt/bin/busybox ps -o pid,etime | sed -n "s/ *1155 \+\([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\).*/expr \1 \\* 60 + \2/p")
+ /opt/bin/busybox ps -o pid,etime
+ sed -n s/ *1155 \+\([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\).*/expr \1 \* 60 + \2/p
+ expr 293 * 60 + 54
17634
```

Note that I also integrated the `grep` into `sed` with the `-n 's///p'` approach (global **n**o-print and then **p**rint on match).

Thanks to @yaegashi for getting me to try `\\` again...

Comment: Nope, this fails.  The difference was the existence of files in the directory or not.  If there are no files, then `*` remains unsubstituted.  Otherwise, it expands and messes up the `expr`.

Answer (score 0):

@yaegashi had the approach right but my `sed` call seems to introduce the need for a third `\`.

```
root@embedded:/data# set -vx
root@embedded:/data# echo Process Uptime: $(eval $(/opt/bin/busybox ps -o pid,etime | sed -n "s/ *${APP_PID} \+\([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\).*/expr \1 \\\* 60 + \2/p"))
echo Process Uptime: $(eval $(/opt/bin/busybox ps -o pid,etime | sed -n "s/ *${APP_PID} \+\([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\).*/expr \1 \\\* 60 + \2/p"))
+ /opt/bin/busybox ps -o pid,etime
+ sed -n s/ *1156 \+\([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\).*/expr \1 \\* 60 + \2/p
+ eval expr 2 \* 60 + 46
+ expr 2 * 60 + 46
+ echo Process Uptime: 166
Process Uptime: 166
```

Fingers crossed that this not only works now, but also continues to do so next time I use it...

Answer (score 0):

This is an awk script which will convert the 0-00:00:00 output to seconds. It is used like this...

```
ps -eo pid,time,user,comm | awk '{print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"$4$5$6$7$8$9$10}' | awk -f _os_return_process_time_in_seconds.awk
```

Here is the script. Just wrote if for another purpose. May have issues still.

```
BEGIN {
   FS="|"
}

{
   pid=$1
   time=$2
   user=$3
   comm=$4
   split_count=split($2,days_array,"\-")
   if ( split_count == 2 ) {
      days=days_array[1]
      hr_min_sec=days_array[2]
   }
   else {
      days=0
      hr_min_sec=days_array[1]
   }
   split_count=split(hr_min_sec,hr_min_sec_array,":")
   if ( split_count == 3 ) {
      hours=hr_min_sec_array[1]
      minutes=hr_min_sec_array[2]
      seconds=hr_min_sec_array[3]
   }
   else if ( split_count == 2 ) {
      hours=0
      minutes=hr_min_sec_array[1]
      seconds=hr_min_sec_array[2]
   }
   else if ( split_count == 1 ) {
      hours=0
      minutes=0
      seconds=hr_min_sec_array[1]
   }
   total_seconds=(days*24*60*60)+(hours*60*60)+(minutes*60)+(seconds)
   print pid"|"total_seconds"|"user"|"comm
}
```