# Output of ps lstart changed

Tags: linux, ps

I started a program and wrote the output of `ps -p PID -o lstart=` to a file, like so:

```
$ long_running_command &
[1] 4562
$ ps -p $! -o lstart= > start_time
$ cat start_time
Wed Apr  6 06:16:31 2016
```

But when I re-run `ps` later I get a slightly different result:

```
$ ps -p 4562 -o lstart=
Wed Apr  6 06:16:53 2016
```

I was under the impression that `lstart=` would print the [start time of a given process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5731234/113632). Why am I getting a different start time when I re-call `ps`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had suspected (but hadn't been able to replicate) that the issue was somehow related to an `exec` call or something similar that was replacing the running process, keeping the same PID but resetting the start time. It turns out the explanation is much simpler (and unfortunately I didn't include enough detail in the original question).

As detailed in [this followup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/274721/19157), an NTP update was changing my system clock between the `ps` calls. Apparently `lstart` respects clock updates (which makes sense, but still somewhat surprised me), meaning that you can't rely on the output of `lstart` to remain consistent over the lifetime of a single process.