# Why is a gap between `journalctl -k -b -0` and `ps ho lstart 1`?

Tags: systemd, ps, systemd-journald, real-time, journalctl

I encounter a strange observation:

If I do: `journalctl -k -b -0 | sed -e 's/^\(.\{76\}\).*/\1.../;3q'`

I will see something like:

> ```
> -- Journal begins at Sun 2022-08-07 12:06:55 CEST, ends at Mon 2023-02-20 08...
> Jan 09 15:07:39 magnet kernel: Linux version 5.10.0-20-amd64 (debian-kernel@...
> Jan 09 15:07:39 magnet kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0...
> ```

Which should match to: `dmesg | sed -e 's/^\(.\{76\}\).*/\1.../;2q'`

> ```
>  [    0.000000] Linux version 5.10.0-20-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org...
>  [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-20-amd64 root=/...
> ```

That's cool, I see first lines of boot with full timestamp!

**But:** If I hit: `ps ho lstart,cmd 1`

> ```
> Mon Jan  9 15:07:26 2023 /sbin/init
> ```

If I correctly interpret: Process **`init`** was started 13 secondes **before** kernel!?

Tested on many other hosts with this kind of command:

```bash
initSeconds() { 
    sdtext=(before after)
    { read -r kstart
      read -r sstart ;} < <(
        date -f <(LC_ALL=C journalctl -k -b -0 |
            sed -e "2{s/$HOSTNAME.*//;q};d"
            LC_ALL=C ps ho lstart 1) +%s
    )
    sdiff=$((sstart-kstart))
    printf 'Kernel : %(%a %d %b %T)T\nSystemd: %(%a %d %b %T)T (%s" %s)\n' \
        $kstart $sstart ${sdiff#-} ${sdtext[sdiff>0]}
}
```

Then

```bash
sudo bash < <(declare -f initSeconds;echo initSeconds)
```

```
Kernel : Mon 09 Jan 11:33:53
Systemd: Mon 09 Jan 11:33:23 (30" before)
```

```bash
ssh pi@raspberrypi sudo bash < <(declare -f initSeconds;echo initSeconds)
```

I've recieved differents results:

- `13"`, `18"`, upto `30"`: `init` **before** *`kernel`*, on differents hosts,
- `-50"`, `-3354` on differents raspberri-pi... where **`init`**  could start upto near than one hour after ***kernel***?

Is this a bug?

If yes (I think so) , is this a `ps` bug or a `journactl` bug!?

Note: I read [Output of ps lstart changed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274809/27653), but I can't agree to see 30 seconds gap in only 41 days!

##### Log extract (from a Lenovo laptop):

( Full command under *root* user:

```
# paste -d\   <( dmesg |
    sed 's/$/                        /;s/^\(.\{32\}\).*/    \1/'
  ) <(
    LANG=C journalctl -k -b -0|sed 's/\(.\{40\}\).*/\1/'
  )
```

)

And some manual edition:

> ```
> |--       dmesg output       --| |--        journalctl output         --|
> -------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
> [    0.000000] Linux version 5.1 -- Journal begins at Sun 2021-10-03 13:2
> [    0.000000] Command line: BOO Feb 26 12:09:12 host kernel: Linux versi
> [    0.000000] x86/fpu: x87 FPU  Feb 26 12:09:12 host kernel: Command lin
> [    0.000000] BIOS-provided phy Feb 26 12:09:12 host kernel: x86/fpu: x8
> [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0 Feb 26 12:09:12 host kernel: BIOS-provid
> [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0 Feb 26 12:09:12 host kernel: BIOS-e820: 
> ... 58 lines skipped
> [    0.018652] RAMDISK: [mem 0x3 Feb 26 12:09:12 host kernel: found SMP M
> ...802 lines skipped
> ...102 lines skipped
> [    4.557467] EXT4-fs (dm-0): m Feb 26 12:09:12 host kernel: PM: Image n
> [    4.623199] Not activating Ma Feb 26 12:09:12 host kernel: EXT4-fs (dm
> [    4.730262] systemd[1]: Inser Feb 26 12:09:12 host kernel: Not activat
> [    4.751319] systemd[1]: syste Feb 26 12:09:12 host systemd[1]: Inserte
> [    4.767877] systemd[1]: Detec Feb 26 12:09:12 host systemd[1]: systemd
> ...140 lines skipped
> [    5.882062] iwlwifi 0000:03:0 Feb 26 12:09:12 host kernel: iwlwifi 000
> [    5.895585] uvcvideo: Found U Feb 26 12:09:12 host kernel: uvcvideo: F
> [    5.898230] input: Integrated Feb 26 12:09:13 host kernel: input: Inte
> [    5.898319] usbcore: register Feb 26 12:09:13 host kernel: usbcore: re
> ... 49 lines skipped
> [   10.702190] e1000e 0000:00:19 Feb 26 12:09:17 host kernel: e1000e 0000
> ```

And

```
initSeconds
Kernel : dim 26 fév 12:09:12
Systemd: dim 26 fév 12:09:07 (5" before)
```

In fact, systemd was started 5 seconds **after** kernel (4.730262), but this won't explain de negative gap.

Comment: IIRC if you look at the kernel logs in `/var/log`, a lot of the initial messages get marked with the same timestamp. It might be something about how the userspace logging process isn't up when the kernel boots, but comes around to storing the logs just a bit later. So you might have lines like `Feb 12 02:11:40 foo1 kernel: [    0.000000] ...` and `Feb 12 02:11:40 foo1 kernel: [   13.834574]` hinting at a 13.8 second delay in this case.

Comment: @ilkkachu No, this because a lot of things could be done along 1 ms. And yes, if you compare `dmesg` output and `journalctl` output, you will see a lot of entries dated **before** filesystem of `/var/log` are mounted R/W. And everything seem correct!

Answer (score 0):

The start time of a process is fundamentally stored in the kernel as "seconds after system boot". You can confirm this by checking [the format of the `/proc/1/stat` file](https://mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/proc.rst#324).

The `ps` command converts it to human-readable wall-clock timestamp *when you run the command*.

The timestamps in the journal, on the other hand, have already been converted from the "seconds since boot" format into UTC-equivalent form (probably Unix timestamps or similar) *at the time the log entries were written*.

Most Raspberry Pi models don't include a battery-backed real-time clock (RTC), so when the kernel boots, the real system time will be uncertain. A decent assumption that most likely will avoid the need to jump time backwards will be to take the last timestamp written to the root filesystem when the system was last running, and add one second, and use that as a system time until a NTP server can be reached.

If the system has been down for a significant amount of time, the first NTP sync will require a significant forwards time jump - but that's safer than turning the clock backwards, and as the system is in the early boot phase anyway, nothing that has a hard requirement for consistent and smooth time should be running yet.

Because system typically starts writing to the journal almost as soon as the root filesystem is ready and writeable, the timestamps of the early boot in the journal will be off by some amount, unless the system has an accurate RTC. When the system time is adjusted, the adjustment event itself should be logged in the journal, but `journald` will **not** go back and adjust the timestamps of already-written log entries. If you review the entire journal, you should see a discontinuity in timestamps at any point the system clock is adjusted.

As a result, the logged timestamps between kernel start-up time and the time the first NTP sync is established should be only interpreted *relative to each other*, as their correspondence to true wall-clock time will be uncertain, **especially** on systems with no accurate battery-backed RTC.

`systemd` actually includes two targets applicable for this: on systems with a RTC, the `time-set.target` marks the point in the boot process where the system clock has been set using the RTC time, and so the system time should be at least in the right ballpark, assuming the RTC is any good.

The second target is `time-sync.target`, which marks the point at which the system clock has been synchronized with NTP or some other reliable external timesource. On systems with no functional battery-backed RTC, like (most) RasPis, any early-boot timestamps logged before reaching this target should be assumed to be usable only in relation with each other.

Comment: I agree, with almost the whole of your post. Anyway, I've tested this on many different hardware, after many successive reboot... I can't agree, with observed gaps. (All this hosts was up with clock already synchronised )